# where is the source code for av_codec_set_pkt_timebase in ffmpeg repo

Tags: ffmpeg, avcodec

I am using libavformat to mux AVI files.

When I look into the ffmpeg source code, I cannot find the function definition for av_codec_set_pkt_timebase while I can only find the function declaration in avcodec.h

I am using git revision: bfdf0f078a7463e1f304ef6fea3b25518cc45c3b

Who can tell where is the function definition for av_codec_set_pkt_timebase?

Best regards,
Lewis

Answer (score 2):

In revision `bfdf0f0`, `av_codec_set_pkt_timebase` is created in `libavcodec/utils.c` on [line 1264](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/bfdf0f0/libavcodec/utils.c#L1264):

```
MAKE_ACCESSORS(AVCodecContext, codec, AVRational, pkt_timebase)
```

`MAKE_ACCESSORS` is a macro defined in `libavutil/internal.h`:

```
#define MAKE_ACCESSORS(str, name, type, field) \
    type av_##name##_get_##field(const str *s) { return s->field; } \
    void av_##name##_set_##field(str *s, type v) { s->field = v; }
```

Comment: Thanks @TachyonVortex